# about the structure of 'prohibiting doing something'

Tags: sentence-structure, structure, phrase-structure

Can I use the altered sentences instead of the original sentence?
The original sentence is from [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prohibit?q=prohibit).

> the original sentence: *The high cost of equipment prohibits many people from taking up this sport.*

> the sentence A: *The high cost of equipment prohibits taking up this sport.*

> the sentence B: *The high cost of equipment prohibits many people taking up this sport.*

This actually arises from wondering about the structures following **prohibit**.
I know structures of the sentence A and B both are correct when **prohibit** is associated with a rule or law as in *The policy prohibits smoking on school grounds* or *The policy prohibits people smoking on school grounds*. But the case I am asking about is when **prohibit** is not associated with a rule or law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly no - neither of your alternatives are correct.

> A: The high cost of equipment prohibits taking up this sport.

This is wrong because it reads as if the high cost blanketly prohibits anyone and everyone from taking up the sport. That isn't true - it only prohibits *some people*, namely those who cannot afford it.

> B: The high cost of equipment prohibits many people taking up this sport.

This is wrong because "people taking up this sport" means people who are *already in the process of taking up the sport*. This sentence reads as if those specific people are prohibited - but from what?

The original sentence is clear - it has a subject, an action, an object affected by that action.

> [The high cost of equipment] **prohibits** [many people] **from** [taking up this sport].

Comment: Thank you very much for your elegant answer, but please would you look through this trouble that confuses me? You said *people taking up this sport* in **B** means people who are already in the process of taking up the sport. But please consider this another correct example from a dictionary, *The policy prohibits people smoking on school grounds*. Here, I think **people smoking on school grounds** doesn't mean people already in the process of smoking, but people's action of smoking. May I ask you for a snippet of explanation regarding this?

Comment: @SmartHumanism Yes. 'People smoking' and 'people taking up smoking' would be two different things. In the first, 'smoking' is a **verb** - the thing that they are doing. In the second, 'smoking' is a **noun** - the name of a habit, and 'taking' is the verb. In your question there is a difference between people *playing* a sport and people *taking it up*.

Comment: I'm sorry but I gotta dare to ask you a bit more as my confusion continues. The part I don't get is why *The high cost of equipment prohibits many people taking up this sport* reads wrong when *The policy prohibits people smoking on school grounds* is correct. The only structural difference is the existence of *many* in the former. Then, is it *many* that makes the former wrong?